# Internal host and port are shown in web page using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, port, host

I have two web sites running on two tomcat servers (separate machine or LAN IPs).  Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  server1.com www.server1.com;

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://192.168.1.141:8080;
    }
}

server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  server2.com www.server2.com;

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://192.168.1.129:8080;
    }
}
```

Nginx runs on the same hardware with server1's IP (192.168.1.141).  Everything seems to work well except when I go to a certain page on server1, all relative URLs on that page (and subsequent pages) becomes `http://192.168.1.141:8080/blah` instead of http://www.server1.com/blah.  There are many pages work fine and maintain the host/port using www.server1.com and default port (80).  I could not find why some pages work while some other pages change the host and port.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved, but I still don't know why it happened.  The problem was with the <base> tag in the problem pages.  I left it empty so it is filled in automatically when the jsp page is rendered.  However, in my other working pages, I did the same thing and the base url is filled properly.  I hard coded my domain into the base url and all these problem pages are working now.

If anyone knows why this happened, I still want to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this line in the proxy blocks

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

This will make the backend servers to detect the external host instead of the internal IP.

**EDIT**

`<base>` tag puts a base for all relative links in the page, like if my page is hosted at `foo.com` and I put a `base = bar.com`, for example a url like this

```
<a href = '/some/random/uri'>click me</a>
```

Normally it should go to `http://foo.com/some/random/uri` but the base will make it point to `bar.com/some/random/uri`

This is why the pages with base worked.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  I removed the hard coded base url and the links are working fine now.  Still not clear why some pages worked with this tag <base/> before adding this header line you suggested here.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. The thing is that the page that worked has the same <base/>.  It was not hard coded which makes me wonder why I had to do it to the non-working pages. Anyway, the problem was gone after using your config line.

Comment: I have another question on nginx.  My Tomcat server's access log always shows the IP from the proxy server's, not the real client IP. I added the following lines, but they didn't seem to fix the problem.  I bet this can be fixed with configuration, but I just could not find the right way to do it. proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my Tomcat version was 6.0.  The valve for passing the real-ip was introduced in a later version.  After getting 6.0.37, it works fine now.

In Tomcat server.xml file, add the following in the Engine block.

```
 <!--pass remote IP into the log-->
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
      remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
      protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
      protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />

In nginx.conf:

  location / {
      proxy_pass      http://saturn.com:81;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```